# Is this a soldier beetle? Bug identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I'm curious to find out what kind of bug this is. Reverse Google image search suggested a type of soldier beetle, but I am not convinced.

The photo is taken in summer, in England

Thanks!

[image: Unknown bug]

Comment: No, it is a longhorn beetle. Cerambicidae.

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange! Generally, for species identification questions, you'll want to include the geographic area and time of day.

Comment: And also the date of photography and the season.

Comment: @KarlKjer You can probably make an answer out of your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very much like *Arhopalus rusticus*, a species of long-horned beetle (Cerambycidae) that is found in England. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arhopalus_rusticus